# Reading a text file in java, want to check what kind of line break it uses

Tags: java, escaping, line-breaks

I'm given two text files, one uses \n for line breaks, the other uses \r\n. I Just want to be able to check which of these two it is. I want to use BufferedReader to read character by character and search for a \ (using \) and then check what the next character is, but when I search through the txt file for any \s, I don't get any results, the loop just ends.

For now, I'm just trying to test by printing out the \ and whatever character follows it, so I should be printing out a bunch of \n or \r when I run the file, but I just get the Done to print. Any advice?

```
char x;
  while(reader.ready())
  {
    x = (char) reader.read();
    if(x == '\\')
         System.out.println(x + "" + (char) reader.read());             
  }
System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: Doesn't reader.read() return an int? Couldn't you be look for the integer value of \r and \n?  http://www.techonthenet.com/ascii/chart.php This shows the values 10 and 13 are new line and carriage return respectively.

Comment: You're confused about what '\n' and '\r' are. They are single characters, not two characters. '\n' has the value ASCII value 10 and '\r' has value 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing one character `\r` and a string consisting of two characters `\` and `r`. The code below should work for you:

```
char charValue;
while ((charValue = (char) reader.read()) != -1) {
    if ('\n' == charValue) {
        System.out.println("\\n");              
    }    
    if ('\r' == charValue) {
        System.out.println("\\r");              
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see what type of text you are parsing.

For example, if your file looks like this:

```
The lazy brown dog\n jumped over the fox.\n
```

Your current code should probably work.  However, if the file looked like this:

```
The lazy brown dog
jumped over the fox
```

Your code wouldn't.  The second file doesn't actually contain the character '\'.  Instead, it contains a line feed and carriage return or just a line feed.  If you were testing for '\n' you would actually want to test for character 0x0A (or character 10).  You would want to test for that instead.

My suggestion would be to make sure you are testing for the right character.  If you are, then posting a sample of the file you are parsing would help make the question clearer.

(I know this should probably be a comment rather than an answer, but I can't post comments right now).